# Capybara - NameError: uninitialized constant Capybara::TimeoutError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara

I am creating integration tests for my rails application.

The application I am working to is a little slow. In my test, I execute a certain action within the website (a "saving" - which reloads in the end the page) and the following capybara action runs before the page is actually reloaded.

I cannot use "sleep (seconds)" as this freezes the "reloading" itself.

So I wanted to give a try to this github idea: https://gist.github.com/metaskills/1172519

but I get the following error:

> NameError: uninitialized constant Capybara::TimeoutError

Can someone tell me why I get this error and what does it mean?

Comment: This is no method, this is a constant. What are you trying to do? Please post more code

Comment: @RaVeN thank you. I updated the page

Answer (score 1):

As you posted, you're trying to make a method which waits for the ajax requests to finish.

But there's a better way to do this:

You have a view, which loads a modal (remote, with ajax). You should not do something like the `wait_until` method. Or even though not with using `while true`.

The best way of doing this, is to set an unique html element on the modals content:

```
<!-- in your modal view/partial -->
<span id="modal"></span>
... modal code
```

When you then use Capybara like this:

```
find("#modal")
```

The `find` method automatically waits for all ajax requests to finish.

See https://www.varvet.com/blog/why-wait_until-was-removed-from-capybara/ for more inputs.

Comment: Thank you RaVeN. But what if I am waiting for the loading of a page identical to the previous one? The fact is that in my script I have a "new" button that simply reload a page with an associated id number. Si, if I use "find", it find the element before reloading the page (this is what happens)

Comment: Then you should use a different dom objecto to find which is unique on the page which is being loaded

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the error is because the `Capybara::TimeoutError` class was removed in Capybara v2, along with the `#wait_until` method.  As the answer by @RaVeN states you should just be telling Capybara to expect some content or elements on the page which will make Capybara wait for it to appear automatically (as long as you're using a JS capable driver)

```
expect(page).to have_content("Some content that appears after the page has loaded")  # will wait up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds for the content to appear
```

or if the path of the page changes you could do

```
expect(page).to have_current_path('<the new path you want to wait to load>')
```

As an aside - there is no reason `sleep` in tests should pause a page loading since the tests, app, browser each run in separate threads/processes assuming you're running a JS capable driver.  If you're not running a JS capable driver and are instead using the default rack_test driver then waiting/sleeping for anything is pointless because every action occurs synchronously.

Comment: Thank you Tom. But what if I am waiting for the loading of a page identical to the previous one? The fact is that in my script I have a "new" button that simply reload a page with an associated id number. Si, if I use "find", it find the element before reloading the page (this is what happens)

Comment: If the page truly is identical then all you can really do easily is sleep for a few seconds, or not test it.  Is there really no difference between the pages, no loading indicator that appears on the page (that you can have capybara wait until it disappears), or no difference in the URL?  It seems like a strange UI to have a button that just reloads the page without showing progress in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: Thank you Tom. Yes, it reloads with a different URL: the button creates a mysql new row, and the page reloads showing the new ID as URL. The problem is that "sleep" *freezes* the page just *before reloading* the page. So, when the "sleep" has finished, the page reloads correctly but still the *find("id=...")* is too fast and checks the page before the "reload" has started (and finds the object because already present in the page).

Comment: Supposing *previous_url = new_page* and  *current_path = saved_page*, even using *assert_not_equal(previous_url, current_path)* fails. Here specifically the result shows: *assert_not_equal(previous_url, previous_url) -> expected previous_url to not be equal to previous_url*. All this shows just how the page reloads slowly and how *sleep* is ineffective because it *freezes* the page *before reloading*.

Comment: @LucaDanieli you shouldn't be using assert_not_equal with urls you should use the Capybara provided assertions/matchers.  If you're using RSpec it's the line with `have_current_path` in my answer, if not its `assert_current_path(<the path you expect>)` .  Also, one more time, IF you're using a JS capable driver, sleep in the test thread won't pause the app thread - what driver are you using?